# Why is more than half of my RAM being used on absolutely nothing?

Tags: windows-10, memory

Recently, I have noticed that more than half(usually 3-5GB) of my ram is being used, with nothing running except for task manager. I have tried some fixes like using RAMMap to clear standby and the Ndu fix, but I still come to the same problem. I sometimes use Razer Cortex to decrease my RAM usage(which usually results to 1GB of RAM freed) but it still concerns me as to why so much RAM is being used by nothing, and sometimes makes browsing slower. If anyone knows any other methods to attempt to fix this, please let me know!

My specs:
(Acer Nitro 5 AN515-52)
8GB DDR4
GTX 1050
Intel Core i5-8300H

[image: Task Manager]
[image: Resource Monitor]

Comment: What would you like to do with a whole lot of "empty RAM"?  Keep it for decoration? Empty RAM is wasted RAM. Clearing it down artificially means every time your OS wants something it thought was in RAM it has to re-fetch it from your drive… wasting time, resources & effort.

Comment: Your attempt at clearing RAM has the same effect as a task killer (normally this term is used on Android devices). You're actually hurting the computer, wasting time, requiring more I/O operations, etc. Once you open apps that are resource-intensive the RAM will allocate to them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does Windows 7 waste my RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/734176/where-does-windows-7-waste-my-ram)

Comment: @JustinThrKoala: It's possible you have something like a driver memory leak but it's hard to tell from your screenshots as there seems to be quite a lot of junk running in the background. Try specifically restarting the laptop (not the same as shutting down then powering on again). If this fixes the problem then you may want to try updating your drivers and/or disabling fast startup. You could also try using RAMMap (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap) to investigate

Comment: 3 to 4 GB memory used on a 64-bit machine is entirely normal. Windows processes and your third party additions use this memory

Comment: There is Physical and Virtual Memory explained here>>>>>https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/physical-and-virtual-memory-in-windows-10/e36fb5bc-9ac8-49af-951c-e7d39b979938

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a professional regarding OS's, however, I assume it stores all recent file access into RAM. Whenever it needs to read again from those files, it uses the RAM instead of re-reading the files.

The actual algorithm might be much more complex, probably working with pages in memory which can be overwritten by RAM 'really' needed for software applications or the OS, and it takes into account when a file has been rewritten.